# How to draw a Taylor diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there any package or a way to draw Taylor diagrams ([From this paper](https://pcmdi.llnl.gov/staff/taylor/CV/Taylor_diagram_primer.pdf?id=87)) easily?

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a dedicated package for *only* these diagrams, but I think you could just do them with `polar axes` that come with pgfplots, particularly see section 5.10.6 Partial Polar Axes of the manual as well as 5.11. SMITH CHARTS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK.  So, I won't do all the work for you.  But, I will do enough so that you should be able to figure out how to add everything else that remains to be done.

[image]

What I show you here is as follows:

- How to clip a portion of a picture
- How to draw concentric circles about a given center
- How to label along a curved path
- How to place a label at a point along a path
- How label at the end points of a line
- How to get different styles of dashed and dotted lines
- How to plot points
- Different approaches to scaling the text

And, I believe that should allow you to complete the rest of the picture.

Here's the code to generate the diagram:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x={(4cm,0)},
  y={(0,4cm)},
  radius=4cm,
  ]
  %% notation (<angle>:<radius>)   gives polar coordinates 
  %%          (<x-coor>,<y-coord>) Euclidean coordinates

  %% draw semi-circles clipped by the 1st quadrant arc
  %% `scope` prevents the entirety of the remainder of
  %%         picture from being clipped.
  \begin{scope}
    \draw[clip] (0,0) -- (1,0) arc (0:90:1) -- cycle;
    \foreach \myr in {1,2,...,5}
      {
        %% draw a circle centered at (5/7,0)
        %% arc starts at point (\myr/6,0) and proceeds through an
        %% angle of 180 degrees with a radius of \myr/6 units
        \draw[blue,densely dotted] (5/7,0) ++ (\myr/6,0) arc (0:180:\myr/6);
      }
  \end{scope}

  %% place a label along one of the above clipped arcs.
  \path (5/7,0) ++ (2/6,0) arc (0:180:2/6) node[pos=0.75,
                                                rotate=0.75*180-90,
                                                anchor=south,
                                                inner sep=4pt,
                                                scale=0.5,
                                                blue] (A) {$0.25$};

  %% label the correlation coefficient values
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=1}
  \foreach \myp in {0,1,2,...,11}
    {
      %% calculate the angle \myangle from the integer \myp
      \pgfmathsetmacro\myangle{{90*(12-\myp)/12}}
      \pgfmathparse{\myp/10}
      \pgfmathroundtozerofill{\pgfmathresult}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\mylabel{\pgfmathresult}
      %% handle labels that don't follow the previous pattern
      \ifdim\mylabel pt=1.0pt%%
        \def\mylabel{0.95}
      \fi
      \ifdim\mylabel pt=1.1pt%%
        \def\mylabel{0.99}%%
      \fi
      %% draw the dashed lines from orgin to arc with labels outside arc
      \draw[gray!50,
            dash pattern=on 1.25pt off 0.5pt,
            line width=0.1pt] (\myangle:1) node[black,
                                                anchor=180+\myangle] 
                                                {$\scriptscriptstyle\mylabel$}  -- (0,0);
    }

  %% labeling along a curve                                        
  %% a fancy approach that's necessary for labels conforming to    
  %% a curved path.  Not necessary for labels along straight lines.
  \path[postaction={decoration={text along path,
                                text align=center,
                                text={Correlation Coefficient}},
                    decorate}]
       (0,1.15) arc (90:0:1.15);

  %% some data points
  \node[blue]           at (35:4/7+1/2*1/7) {$\diamond$};
  \node[red,scale=0.5]  at (32:5/7)         {$\pmb{\triangle}$};

  %% draw the quarter circle in the first quadrant
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) arc (0:90:1) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```